# Sufficient conditions for gradient descent convergence

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convexity, convex-analysis, limits-and-convergence

I have an unconstrained optimisation problem with convex objective function $f(x)$. Suppose I have access only to some function of the gradient $\hat{\nabla}= g(\nabla f)$, and I take gradient steps treating $\hat{\nabla}$ as the true gradient:
\begin{equation}
  x^{t+1} = x^{t} - \lambda \hat{\nabla}
\end{equation}

What are sufficient conditions on $g$ such that this converges to the optima? In particular, are there results of the form "if $\|\hat{\nabla}-\nabla\|<\epsilon$ and some-property-of-$f$ then gradient descent treating $\hat{\nabla}$ as the gradient converges to the optima"?

Comment: Are there further restrictions on $g$? Do you know the form of $g$? Is it linear? Nonlinear? It seems to me that it's difficult to develop general sufficiency conditions on an arbitrary $g$. For instance, we may say that a necessary condition might be that $g$ ought to have the same sign as $\nabla f$, but if $g$ is a nonlinear function that changes signs depending on the region, this statement may be problematic. A trivial sufficiency condition would be that $g(x) = x$.

Comment: Oh, it seems that I just took $g$ to be the identity map. More generally, we can have $g(\nabla f(x)) = D\nabla f(x)$, where $D$ is a strictly positive definite matrix. That would ensure that $g(\nabla f(x))$ is a descent direction. Given that, and some minor technical assumptions, should ensure sufficiency. However, if $g$ is allowed to be a nonlinear transformation, then things can be trickier. However, maybe you have a more specific $g$ is mind?

Comment: There are certainly convergence theorems that work as long as the step direction is a descent direction for the function being minimized and the step length is selected so as to satisfy some special conditions (e.g. the Armijo conditions.)  I don't think it's possible to say much more without knowing exactly what's being done to the gradient.  

Comment: Based on Brian's comment, perhaps broad sufficiency conditions would be that $g$ (1) maps to a descent direction; and (2) satisfies Armijo conditions in the domain of interest. Those are pretty general conditions, but it's harder to get more specific without additional restrictions on $g$. 

Comment: Thanks all. In the problem I'm working with, $f$ is a sum over a large number of hinge losses $h_i$, and $g$ is an algorithm that computes the gradient of $\hat{f} = \sum h_j$ where $j$ ranges over some but not all of the $i$'s. In fact I know lots about the structure of $g$, but at the moment this is in the form of an algorithmic description of $g$ not directly amenable to reasoning about convergence. My goal is to prove that gradient descent using $g$ converges to the optima, and I'm trying to figure out what I should prove about $g$ to show this.

Comment: Ah, there may be another difficulty here. Hinge loss functions are non-smooth, and many standard convergence proofs generally stipulate that the function of interest is at least once-differentiable everywhere. The standard gradient descent method is undefined for non-differentiable functions. One may need to look at subgradient methods or bundle methods which may have completely different convergence criteria. (I'm not familiar with those)

Comment: @Alex: As Gilead has pointed out, because you are dealing with a non-differentiable loss function, we are in a totally different setup: the primary reason being that an arbitrary subgradient does not yield a "descent direction", whereby, some other juggling has to be done to ensure convergence. And, given your description now I see how to prove convergence of the kind you have in mind. Because your problem is convex, this can be done. Please edit your question to ask the actual thing you have in mind, then maybe one can provide a more precise answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after reading your comments, and some thinking, here is one way to tackle what seems to be going on:

1. You have a nondifferentiable loss function.
2. You wish to compute a subgradient of the loss, but the subgradient is too expensive to compute
3. So you compute only a small part of some subgradient.

This is, the classic setting of an **inexact subgradient projection** method, where essentially you are iterating as follows:

$$
x^{k+1} = \Pi_X(x^k - \alpha_k(g^k+e^k)),
$$
where $g^k$ is a subgradient of your loss function and $e^k$ is an *error* in the subgradient computation, which can be used to model the fact that you are not using all the components of the loss function to compute a subgradient.

Depending on what you are doing, this type of method might be cast as an *online*, *stochastic*, or *incremental* subgradient method.

I recommend that you have a look at the recent survey, your *inexact* computations will probably fit the general frameworks discussed therein.

> **D. P. Bertsekas**, "*Incremental Gradient, Subgradient, and Proximal Methods for Convex Optimization: A Survey*", Lab. for Information and Decision Systems Report LIDS-P-2848, MIT, August 2010; this is an extended version of a chapter in the edited volume **Optimization for Machine Learning**, by S. Sra, S. Nowozin, and S. J. Wright, MIT Press, Cambridge, MA, 2012, pp. 85-119.

Comment: I'm confused- the original poster referred to the gradient as if this was a smooth problem.  How did we jump to considering nonsmooth problems?  


Comment: @Brian, in a comment, he mentioned that the objective $f$ was a sum of hinge losses. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss